# what is the best Approach to segregate data from Room Database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have data stored in local room database in android .

```
[
    {
    id:1
    name: Dhiraj kumar
    phone:1234567
    email:test@test.com
    school: DAV
    },
    {
    id:2
    name: Niraj kumar
    Phone:2453465345
    email:test@test.com
    school: DAV
    },
    {
    Id:3
    name: some name
    Phone:134245
    email:test@test.com
    school: DAV
    },
    {
    Id:4
    name: Sumanth
    Phone:134245
    email:test@test.com
    school: summer vila
    },
    {
    Id:3
    name:Raghav
    Phone:134245
    email:test@test.com
    school: summer vila
    }
    ]
```

> I want to get the list of school with the all student list

```
ex: 


     [{
        "school": DAV
        "students":
        [
         {
                id:1
                name: Dhiraj kumar
                phone:1234567
                email:test@test.com
                school: DAV
                },
                {
                id:2
                name: Niraj kumar
                Phone:2453465345
                email:test@test.com
                school: DAV
                },
                {
                Id:3
                name: some name
                Phone:134245
                email:test@test.com
                school: DAV
                }
        ]
},
  {
    "school":summer villa
    "students"[
 {
        Id:4
        name: Sumanth
        Phone:134245
        email:test@test.com
        school: summer vila
        },
        {
        Id:3
        name:Raghav
        Phone:134245
        email:test@test.com
        school: summer vila
        }
]
}      
        ]
```

currently i am doing fetching Distinct school names , then running loop and then fetching List of students where school is `schoolName` .

But i want to know, how can i get data using query ? is it possible , or what is the best approach to segregate data ?

Comment: You should post the entities you use with Room.